# docker-compose,ビルドする際に出力されるConnection failedエラーについて

Tags: docker, network, docker-compose, apt

こんにちは。
docker-composeを使って、Laravel,mysql,phpmyadminの環境を構築しています。

Dockerfileをもとにビルドしようとすると下記のエラーが出力されます。

## やったこと

・googleでひたすら同じ事象がないか検索しましたが見つからない
・先輩にコードをcloneしてもらって別環境でビルドしてもらったが先輩の環境ではなんの問題もなくビルド成功

## やろうとしたこと

・コンテナ内にある/etc/apt/sorces.listファイル内を直接書き換えようと思ったがDockerfile内での記述がややこしくなりそう&その書き換えによって回復する問題ではなさそうと思った

## 解決したいこと

下記のエラーの原因(一時的な向こう側のURLエラー?)が知りたい。どうしたらエラーを出さずに環境構築できるかが知りたい。

[image: エラー内容]

```
Step 4/10 : RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpq-dev mariadb-client unzip  && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql mysqli   && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
 ---> Running in ed73137c5ccf
Err:1 http://security.debia.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.64.204 80]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.230.133 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.230.133 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.230.133 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.64.204 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian..org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.230.133 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libzip-dev
E: Unable to locate package libpq-dev
E: Unable to locate package mariadb-client
E: Unable to locate package unzip
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpq-dev mariadb-client unzip  && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql mysqli   && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

## 追記

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
COPY ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY ./apache/*.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpq-dev mariadb-client unzip\
  && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql mysqli \
  && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Composer install
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
  ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
  ENV COMPOSER_HOME /composer
  ENV PATH $PATH:/composer/vendor/bin

WORKDIR /var/www/

RUN composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Comment: 念のため、`Dockerfile` ファイルの内容も質問中に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: VPN 環境下などで作業されていますか？　たとえば（Docker の中ではなく）ホストのネットワークから http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease にアクセスできますか？

Comment: Dockerfileを追記しました。

Comment: VPN環境下ではなく、ホストで作業しています。ホストのネットワークからそちらのURLへアクセスできませんでした。ネットワークに問題があるんですかね ...

Answer (score 1):

こちら解決しました。

デバイスに入れていた、セキュリティソフトが邪魔をしていたみたいで無効に設定すると問題なくビルドできました。